# Display data in built in CalendarView

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

i am working on CalendarView.i am adding event in Calendar with this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
                intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivity(intent);
```

when device is offline, event saved in device's locale calendar.

now the problem is:
"Sony ericsson" has facility to store Calendar-entry locally. but when i use "Micromax-tablet", there is no facility to store calendar-entry locally,you have to store calendar-entry on google-calendar.

so,what should be solution?
solution may be save data into database.suppose i have some birth-date in "myBirthday" variable.

now my question is how to display data to CalendarView(on cell of date)?

any suggestion will be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here you have fully tutorial about Calendar intents.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents)**

It will help you.

Comment: thanks veRy much @Ty221.it's veRy useful to me. i'll come back with errors.

Comment: it's ok. your answer is definitely acceptable.  i've read it.this tutorial helped about saving calendar-events in the device.
but as i said,micromax tablet have not facility to store calendar-event locally and have to store at "google-calendar" or "exchange".
when i am offline,then what should i do about that???

Comment: @Rum There are two possibilities : 1. Create your own Calendar mechanism, 2. Save everything in cache and on online send it to Google

Comment: i want to use way to use built-in calendarView and save event in cache.
@Ty221, can u give me some hints or links to do that.

Comment: can i use content-provider for that??and how?

Comment: @Rum I will answer you tomorrow, current I cannot I have very important task. Sorry